# Convert php code to objectiveC

Tags: php, objective-c, arrays, magento

Hi I've this php code:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$quoteId = $proxy->call( $sessionId, 'cart.create');

$arrProducts = array(
    array(
        “product_id” => “1”,
        “qty” => 2
    );

$resultCartProductAdd = $proxy->call(
    $sessionId,
    “cart_product.add”,
    array(
        $quoteId,
        $arrProducts
    )
);
```

I need to use it in my iOS app so I'm getting the `sessionId` and the `quoteId` by using a library. The library that I'm using work so:
Magento gives me this api: [`customer.create`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.create.html) and I've to set in customer create the sessionId and an array in which I put the details of the customer. In objectiveC I'm getting this code:

```
[Magento call:@[@"customer.create", @{
     @"email": email,
     @"password": password,
     @"firstname": firstname,
     @"lastname": lastname,
     @"website_id": @1,
     @"store_id": Magento.service.storeID
}] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    Magento.service.customerID = responseObject;
    NSLog(@"signUp customerID = %@", Magento.service.customerID);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Now I'm guessing that my library convert a php array to a NSDictionary (look the code above). How I can transform the php array of array (by using this library) in objectiveC?
I've to use the [`cart_product.add`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html) magento api.
I hope you can understand what I mean and I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself, here's the code:

```
[Magento call:@[@"cart_product.add", Magento.service.cartID,@[@{@"product_id": productID, @"qty": self.qty}]]
                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                            NSLog(@"Prodotto aggiunto");
                            [Magento call:@[@"cart.info", @{@"quoteId": Magento.service.cartID}]
                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                      [self getListOfProductsInCart:responseObject];
                                  }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"Errore: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                  }];
```

With this code converted the php you saw in my question to objectiveC. I hope this will be useful for someone